# How can you set up dynamically loaded library dependencies in bazel?

Tags: c++, bazel

Suppose I have a unit test that uses `dlopen` to load and call code from a provided shared library

```
int main(int argc, char* argv[]) {
  const char* library = argv[1];
  // calls dlopen with library and does some testing
}
```

Given the declared library

```
cc_library(
    name = "a",
    srcs = ["a.cpp"],
    visibility = ["//visibility:public"],
)
```

Is there any way I can use `cc_test` to set up the unit test to run with the location of library `a` passed in as an argument? (Preferably also in a platform independent way so that I don't have to worry about what suffix is used for the library)

Comment: I'm not sure about getting it passed as an argument, but if you supply it to the cc_test rule's "data" property then it should be symlinked into it's runfiles directory when the tests are executed, which might help you to locate it some other way.

Comment: ok - I see it... though the path seems to have some architecture and platform dependent parts to it

Comment: You might be able to use `cc_test.args` to tell the test where the data is. E.g.:
`cc_test(name=..., srcs=..., deps=..., data=[":foo"], args=["--foo=$(location :foo)"])`

Comment: `$(location :a)` unfortunately gives me an inaccessible path like `./liba.so` instead of the path `./_solib_darwin_x86_64/libliba.so` that's set up by `data`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You might be able to write a custom skylark rule that accesses runfiles (related discussion [here](https://groups.google.com/forum/#!topic/bazel-discuss/uvwAQqWthaE)).

Hacking something together:

BUILD:

```
load("//:foo.bzl", "runfiles")

cc_binary(
    name = "liba.so",
    srcs = [ "a.cc" ],
    linkshared = 1,
)

runfiles(
    name = "runfiles",
    deps = [ ":liba.so" ],
)
```

foo.bzl:

```
def _impl(ctx):
  for dep in ctx.attr.deps:
    print(dep.files_to_run.executable.path)

runfiles = rule(
  implementation = _impl,
  attrs = {
    "deps": attr.label_list(allow_files=True),
  }
)
```